# What does this particular line in java using indexOf mean?

Tags: java, arrays

My Code:

```
// Import scanner class
import java.util.Scanner;

// Create class and method
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Press any key to start");
String key = inp.nextLine();
System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
System.out.println("Upto 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

int counter = 0;
int index = 0;
double[] numbers = new double[5];

boolean go = true;

while(go) {           
    String value = inp.nextLine();      
    
    int indexOfH = value.indexOf("h");
    boolean containsH = indexOfH == 0 || indexOfH == (value.length()-1);

    if(containsH){ //Validate h at beginning or end 
        numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));
          System.out.println("HST will be taken account for this value");
    }
    counter++;
    if (counter == 5){
      go = false;
    }
}
System.out.println("Printing Valid values");

for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

What does this line in my code mean?: `numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));

I am new to java arrays, so can you explain it in a simple and easy way?
`

Comment: Which part of that statement is not clear to you, and did you take a look at the official JavaDoc of the methods called and Classes used?

Comment: I posted the statement

Comment: Also: In your title you are asking about a "line ... using indexOf" while in your question itself you ask about a line that doesn't call the indexOf method at all. Having your title and actual question asking 2 different things is confusing at best and makes answering unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Did you post this question yesterday (or before)?

Answer (score 2):

```
int indexOfH = value.indexOf("h");
boolean containsH = indexOfH == 0 || indexOfH == (value.length()-1);
```

`indexOfH` is the char position in the string where `"h"` is found.
More clear would have been:

```
int indexOfH = value.indexOf("h");
boolean containsH = value.startsWith("h") || value.endsWith("h");
```

Evidently "h" was a marker.

The `value` is stripped by

```
String numValue = value.replace("h", "");
```

And can then be converted to a double:

```
    numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(numValue);
```

(So `value` might have contained `"3.14h"` or `"h2.89"`.)

An other note: `value.indexOf('h')` would have been more logical, as now the position of a char instead of an entire String is sought.